# Laravel 5.1 - Retrieving single Models using string instead of the name of the model

Tags: laravel-5.1

Sorry for title. I don't know what to write.
This is my problem:
If i write this is all ok:

```
  $obj_license = License::where('licenses.company_id',$company->id)->first();
```

But this throw an error:

```
 $license='License';
 $obj_license = $license::where('licenses.company_id',$company->id)->first();
```

ERROR: `Class 'Butchery_license' not found`

This is just an example. I really need to have the second way working. There is a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use full path to a class:

```
$license='App\License';
$obj_license = $license::where('licenses.company_id',$company->id)->first();
```

Comment: Right! BUt i do not understand why :|

Comment: I'm not PHP guru, I just know that sometimes you should use full path or aliases (use ... as ...) to make it work. So it works now?

Comment: Yep, but this works without full path.   $obj_license = License::where('licenses.company_id',$company->id)->first(); ..THX :)